# Can we capture live object of one program into another program?

Tags: python-3.x, celery

If suppose we have a **program1** inside that we are creating one object.

Now we have one **object**.

In the second program can we capture this **object** with out again **instantiate**,

Assume that **program1** is still running and object is alive.

Actually we are using **python celery**, this always running and object is alive which i was created inside the code. my aim to capture that live object into another program.

is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Short Answer:  kind-of.
Long-answer:  you can't ever get "live objects" in a distributed environment unless you are doing something like CORBA.  Instead, anytime you use celery, you are serializing objects onto and deserializing objects from a broker.  Similarly, you can serialize return values as objects into the results backend.  So, you can have celery serialize python objects by using the [pickle serializer](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/configuration.html#result-accept-content).  But, in no circumstance will you get a live object.  Instead, what you will be getting is your own copy of the object that Celery was working on.